# Fuses blow and sparks appear when using my home's wiring circuits

Tags: switch, electrical-panel, uk

I have recently had issues with different electrical appliances / light bulb / bathroom wiring packing up.

If you put 4 bulbs in different areas of the house, you can guarantee that 1 or 2 will blow off within the first 2 weeks. The surges are irregular and a pattern cannot be put on them.

The house is about 55 years old and a few of the cables are touching the floor, a sizzle and spark often happens when taking the plugs in and out.
[image: Location of Socket]

We have a lot of sockets which are about 1cm off the floor and not more. The  fuse switch box is as per the image:

[image: Fuse switch box]

Would I need to do a complete rewiring of the house? Do I need to change the switch box? Or, what do I need to do to correct the current as-built issues?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong from your description or photos, my best advice is to call in a local electrician. I expect he will advise (and I would agree with him) to replace the fuse box with a modern consumer unit, as they are safer. Whether this will require a rewire, I couldn't say. I'm sure one of the electricians on here will comment/answer soon who might have some better idea than me.

Comment: For power surges, I'd check with a voltage meter to see if you can find a pattern. A faulty neutral would show as one hot leg with low voltage and the other leg with high voltage (so you'd need to check multiple circuits), spiking when larger appliances are used.

Comment: What does "wiring packing up" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I have recently had issues with different electrical appliances ...**

Having the outlets very low down must put a strain on the leads where they enter the plug. Other than that any suspected problems with the electrical supply need to be discussed with the supplier.

> **/ light bulb ...**

Incandescent bulbs tend to fail when there is problems with the supply voltage (i.e. surges) - that is something your electricity supply should be able to help with. Another cause is if the lamp housing/fixture gets too hot.

However, nowadays you should be using CFL or LED lamps. LEDs in particular need adequate airflow to keep them cool - many older bathroom light fittings don't allow for this as they are designed to keep out steamy humid air (and fingers)

> **/ bathroom wiring packing up.**

That sounds very alarming. Ideally there shouldn't be much wiring in a bathroom. A light, maybe an electric shower and a towel rail, maybe a shaver outlet. Given the age and quality of what is visible in photos, I'd consult an electrician.

> **a sizzle and spark often happens when taking the plugs in and out.**

That shouldn't happen if you turn off the switch at the outlet first.

Sparking tends to erode contacts and cause further sparking. The outlets might need replacing (I'd get them moved higher up the wall, with wiring suitably protected in a channel chased into the plaster).

> **do I need to change the switch box?**

As AndyT commented - you might not strictly *need* to but many people would *want* that old-style fusebox replaced by a modern consumer unit with RCD protection (or RCBOs to make later fault-finding easier)